# Cassandra issue with starting and stopping

Tags: ubuntu, cassandra

I recently installed cassandra 2.0.1. I had cassandra 1.2.5 installed before, but I ended up just removing the old version and installing the new, since no critical data were stored.

However I'm getting some pretty weird behavior. I have configured the cluster and everything seems to be fine. The cluster is running on Ubuntu 12.04. In the past I have used sudo service cassandra status/start/stop/... to start and stop cassandra (this is a packaged installation btw).

However right now, the sudo service cassandra status always reports that cassandra is not running (whether I start/stop whatever). On the other hand when I run nodetool status on the nodes, all of the nodes seem to be up and communicating normally.

Is this just a bug? Or is it something that I should further investigate? (e.g. wrong configuration or smthin). Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bug in the init script, fixed in the upcoming 2.0.2: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6101

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification, so in order to check if everything is running properly, nodetool status should be used right?